# Elements of Char Array are right aligned when printed

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print out the letters already used in Hangman i.e. elements in `char array` but they are appearing one by one from the right rather then from the left.  E.g the first letter appears in the 26th location.  The second takes up the 25th or 26th location (depending on alpha order) and so on... Advice would be much appreciated.

Lives : 5
Word : B _ _ _ 
Letters used so far :                         BY

Lives : 4
Word : B _ _ _ 
Letters used so far :                        BEY

Lives : 4
Word : B O O _ 
Letters used so far :                       BEOY

```
char[] lettersUsedCharArray = new char[26];


/**************************************************
* Method - add guessLetter to lettersUsedCharArray
* 
**************************************************/
public void addGuessLetter(char guessLetter)
{
    this.guessLetter = guessLetter;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.lettersUsedCharArray.length; i++)
    {   
        if (this.lettersUsedCharArray[i]== '\0')
        {
                this.lettersUsedCharArray[i]=this.guessLetter;
                break;
        }   
    }
    Arrays.sort(this.lettersUsedCharArray);
}

/**************************************************
 * Method - print out out letters used
 * 
 **************************************************/
public void printLettersUsedCharArray(char[] lettersUsedCharArray, OutputBox oBox)
{
    oBox.print("Letters used so far : ");
    for(int i = 0; i < lettersUsedCharArray.length; i++)
    {
        oBox.print(lettersUsedCharArray[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem correctly. Can you show what you have and what you want? If you want to reverse the appearance, just reverse the array or print them in the loop starting from the last index, going down to the first index.

Comment: Is using an ArrayList for 'lettersUsedCharArray' out of the question? It seems that would make your life easier in this case.

Comment: As you start with all `'\0'` sorting will put the entire array will put them at the beginning. Go for @SoulDZIN's tip.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

If you are trying to sort your array this way `[b,a,_,_]`--> `[a,b,_,_]` (lest say that `_` is "empty" place) with with `Arrays.sort` then to avoid placing `_` marks at beginning you should specify range that must be sorted, like in this example:

```
char[] arr = new char[4];
arr[0] = 'B';
arr[1] = 'A';

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // before sorting: [B, A, , ]
Arrays.sort(arr, 0, 2);// sort from 0 index (inclusive) to 2 index (exclusive) 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // after sorting: [A, B, , ]
```

So in your case to add char to array you can iterate over array till you find empty space, place that letter to array and sort it with `Arrays.sort(arr, 0, i+1)`.

Comment: Thank you both.  To explain a little further the char array seems to add the letters one by one to end of array so when I then sort and print them the output is something like e.g. "                      BEOY" i.e. 22 white spaces before the 4 letters. If I print out in reverse order as was suggested by Quoi above then the letters will appear before the white spaces but in reverse alpha order.  So what I don't understand is why the letters aren't stored in the start of Array ?  Pshemo this may have been what you were explaining to me but unfort I don't follow you yet.  Beginner here ! @quoi

Comment: @user2035101 check my updated answer (sorry for late reaction bud I somehow missed notification of your massage).